# Storing data from R to DB2 doesn't work

Tags: r, database, db2, rodbc

I have a strange issue with DB2 and R connectivity. I can access the DB, can query the data but I can't store it from R. I use the RODBC package of R. I followed the guide written here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1402db2andr/index.html technically this package creates an "INSERT INTO" statement from the R object and executes it on DB2 to store the data from R. (I have the necessary credentials to execute these operations on the database.)

What I tried is the following (I use R and SQuirreL - http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/ - together to test more than one way):

Creating a test table with 3 columns and 25 records with SQuirreL.
Then I query this table from R.
I try to save the first record from resulting dataset (from 2) into the same table.
Then I query the table from R - with the appended row.
Then I query from SQuirreL.
The issue occures here, while I'm connected to R and after the INSERT. At (4) I see the added record, but I cannot query it from SQuirreL (5). It seems like R has locked the whole table. It doesn't get solved when I disconnect from the DB with R, I also get 2 error messages (I suspect these are related). When I quit R then it is solved and I can query my table from SQuirreL, but the appended record disappears.

I tried to run the same SQL statement from SQuirreL which is sent by R. I get no error messages and the record is appended. Hence the method used by R should work. I don't know where it goes sideways.

I attached a sample data from my table and the used R script (runtime messages included). Below is the CREATE TABLE statement. The table doesn't have any indices or keys yet, so adding a duplicate record is not prohibited.

```
     create table dm_quant.test (
         r_date         date, 
         cid             varchar(255),
         priv_person     varchar(255)
     );
```

Have anyone faced the same difficulties? If so how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

```
    #connect-to-db2
    rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
    gc(reset = TRUE)

    require(RODBC)

    dsn_name <- "DB2_DB"
    user <- "user"
    pwd <- "pass"


    channel <- odbcConnect(dsn = dsn_name, uid = user, pwd)

    table_list <- sqlTables(channel, tableType = "TABLE", schema = "DM_QUANT")
    cat("There are", nrow(table_list), "tables in the DM_QUANT schema.\n")
    # There are 4 tables in the DM_QUANT schema.

    table_name <- "DM_QUANT.TEST"
    col_list <- sqlColumns(channel, table_name)
    cat("There are", nrow(col_list), "columns defined in", table_name,"\n")
    # There are 3 columns defined in DM_QUANT.TEST 

    ## Fetch test table (25 records)
    test_tbl <- sqlQuery(channel, paste("SELECT * FROM ", table_name, sep = ""),
                         as.is = TRUE, na.strings = "")

    ## Determine varTypes parameter for sqlSave
    db2_var_types <- data.frame(var = col_list$COLUMN_NAME, 
                                var_type = col_list$TYPE_NAME, 
                                var_type_ext = paste(col_list$TYPE_NAME, "(", col_list$COLUMN_SIZE, ")", sep = ""),
                                stringsAsFactors = F)

    db2_var_types$final_var_type <- db2_var_types$var_type

    ## Adding size for VARCHAR variable type.
    db2_var_types$final_var_type[db2_var_types$var_type == "VARCHAR"] <- db2_var_types$var_type_ext[db2_var_types$var_type == "VARCHAR"]


    ## Append - append 1st record of the current table again.
    sqlSave(channel, test_tbl[1,], tablename = table_name, append = T, verbose = T, 
            fast = F, rownames = F, colnames = F, varTypes = db2_var_types$final_var_type)
    # Query: INSERT INTO DM_QUANT.TEST ( "R_DATE", "CID", "PRIV_PERSON" ) VALUES ( '2016-06-30', '193303', 'N' )

    ## After I use sqlSave I cannot query from the database from SQuirreL SQL Client.
    ## Seems like I'm locking the whole table by R.

    ## Test append
    ## customer_test <- sqlFetch(channel, table_name)
    test_append <- sqlQuery(channel, paste("SELECT * FROM ", table_name, sep = ""),
                              as.is = TRUE, na.strings = "")

    nrow(test_append)
    # [1] 26
    nrow(test_append) == nrow(test_tbl) + 1
    # [1] TRUE

    ## Append seems successfull
    cat("Record appended successfully.\n")


    ## Close connections
    odbcCloseAll()
    cat("Database connections are closed.\n")

    ## Always closes with 2 error message
    # 1: [RODBC] Error in SQLDisconnect 
    # 2: [RODBC] Error in SQLFreeconnect 

    ## I still cannot query from SQuirreL SQL Client untill I close R completely
    ## After I close and test query from SQuirreL, I cannot see the appended record.
```

The Excel file i used for the test.

```
        **sample-data** 
    R_DATE      CID    PRIV_PERSON
    2016.06.30  193303  N
    2016.06.30  808739  N
    2016.06.30  585008  N
    2016.06.30  479872  N
    2016.06.30  350290  N
    2016.06.30  895961  N
    2016.06.30  822839  N
    2016.06.30  746603  N
    2016.06.30  174107  N
    2016.06.30  858942  N
    2016.06.30  710500  N
    2016.06.30  513533  N
    2016.06.30  303993  N
    2016.06.30  14983   N
    2016.06.30  91401   N
    2016.06.30  364451  N
    2016.06.30  147311  N
    2016.06.30  165897  N
    2016.06.30  988524  N
    2016.06.30  445691  N
    2016.06.30  119082  N
    2016.06.30  4668    N
    2016.06.30  8910    N
    2017.12.31  377879  
    2016.06.30  531661  N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled auto-commit would explain this behaviour. Updated or inserted rows remain locked exclusively until they are committed. When you forcefully close the connection, the changes are likely being rolled back.

Try `odbcSetAutoCommit(channel, autoCommit = TRUE)` right after establishing the connection. Alternatively, you can issue `odbcEndTran(channel, commit = TRUE)` after your `sqlSave()`.